# How to set the style of GXT's Info.display?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm using GXT's `Info` class to display messages/notifications. I'm trying to change the style of my Info class using this :

```
NotificationInfo info = new NotificationInfo(); // extends Info class
// Configuration
InfoConfig config = new DefaultInfoConfig(title, message);
config.setDisplay(milliseconds);
// Formatting
info.setStyleName("background-color:#f9ff4f;text-align:center;" + "border:0x solid black; padding: 3px; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;");
info.show(config);
```

But it's not working! Any Pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: styleName should point to style in your CSS file?

Comment: Also which version of GXT you are using.

Comment: i'm using the latest version of GXT inside a GWT app.

Answer (score 1):

This should work... (for GXT3 it does anyway)

```
info.getElement().applyStyles("background-color:#f9ff4f;text-align:center;" + "border:0x solid black; padding: 3px; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;");
```

By the way, if you need to do a similar thing for a gwt widget (that you are using in your GXT app) you can do...

```
info.getElement().<XElement> cast().applyStyles("background-color:#f9ff4f;text-align:center;" + "border:0x solid black; padding: 3px; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;");
```

NOTE:  I am not sure about the merits of setting it inline like this, but setting a css style just fails (ok the style is set on element but the actual place you want to change gets rendered in a div in a td in table down the line and the div overrides your the value inherit from the css you set).  Best practice is surely to go the full appearances route for GXT3 widgets but that's a lot of work for a small change and so I do use the above sometimes.

Comment: Yes i'm using it inside a GWT app. I use the getElement() and it works but kinda ugly!! i can see the parent's formatting in the background (black background and white text). Well i'll try the applyStyles ;)

Answer (score 1):

Applying styles is only a quick solution and not the best, because GWT `CssResource` has few advantages than direct CSS applying like minification, validation. As mentioned in another answer the best approach is to create an appearance for including your styles and replace the appearance of the `NotificationInfo` with your one. I have previously answered to a similar question. Think it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15222404/1293087